# how to parse xml file using simplexml and create multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am trying to parse a xml file as below to create a  multidimensional array .

```
 <workbook  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" >
<Worksheet ss:Name="45">
  <Table>
       <Row><Cell><Data>232</Data></Cell></Row>
   <Row><Cell><Data>Apple</Data></Cell></Row>
  </Table>
</Worksheet>
<Worksheet ss:Name="46 - new">
  <Table>
       <Row><Cell><Data>876</Data></Cell></Row>
   <Row><Cell><Data>samsung</Data></Cell></Row>
   </Table>
</Worksheet>
```

Here is the code thus far.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$result= array();
foreach($xml->Worksheet as $worksheet ) {
  $result['tab']['name'][]=$worksheet->attributes('ss', TRUE)->Name;
  foreach($worksheet as $table){
    foreach($table as $row){
      foreach($row as  $cell){
        $result['tab']['units'][]=$cell->Data;
      }
    }
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

I am trying to get array as below :

```
items =[
   tab=>[
   'name' => '45',
   'units'=>[
      ['0'=>'232'],
      ['1'=>'Apple']
   ]
   ]
   tab=>[
   'name' => '46-new',
   'units'=>[
      ['0'=>'876'],
      ['1'=>'samsung']
   ]
   ]
 ];
```

but i'm getting the result  as below .

```
array(
    [tab]=>array(
       [name]=>array
       (
          [0]=>SimpleXmlElement Object
           ( 
             [0]=> 45
           )
          [1]=>SimpleXmlElement object
           ( 
             [1]=>46-new
           )
       )
       [units]=>array
       (
          [0]=>SimpleXmlElement Object
           ( 
             [0]=> Nr
           )
          [1]=>SimpleXmlElement object
           ( 
             [0]=>model
           )
           [2]=>SimpleXmlElement Object
           ( 
             [0]=> 232
           )
          [3]=>SimpleXmlElement object
           ( 
             [0]=>apple
           ) 
           .........
       )

    )
)
```

it's quite challenging .How should the code be modified to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do the code as below:

```
$xmlfile = 'xmlfile.xml';
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$result= array();
$i=0;
foreach($xml->Worksheet as $worksheet ) {
$i++;
$result['tab'][$i] = array();
$result['tab'][$i]['name']=(string) $worksheet->attributes("ss", true)->Name;
$pos=0;
$key = '';
 foreach($worksheet as $table){
    foreach($table as $row){
      foreach($row as  $cell){
        $result['tab'][$i]['units'][] = array( "" + $pos => (string) $cell->Data);
        $pos++;
      }
    }
  }
}

return $result;
```

Comment: what do you want to achieeve by these changes?...atleast i was getting something with my code . can you explain it plz

Comment: Sorry @nohan, i forgot to put $i in the inner foreach. There is a need to cast the element to string, I am not sure if the cast to string I put now is the most correct way to do too, but try and tell me.

Comment: Sorry again, I fixed now, try again.

Comment: I changed the cod to do exactly as you expect. If you like the solution don´t forget to vote in that, please ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same key in your array (tab) more than once, so that will need to change to be a unique value.

Also, your xml layout doesn't lend itself well to looping through it like you have. If you assume that your table will always have 4 rows then you can make this work.

Try something like this...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$result= array();
foreach($xml->Worksheet as $key=>$worksheet ) {
  $result['tab'.($key+1)]['name']=$worksheet->attributes('ss', TRUE)->Name;
  foreach($worksheet as $table){
    $label1 = $table[0][0][0]; // row 0, cell 0, data 0
    $label2 = $table[1][0][0]; // row 1, cell 0, data 0
    $value1 = $table[2][0][0]; // row 2, cell 0, data 0
    $value2 = $table[3][0][0]; // row 3, cell 0, data 0
    $result['tab'.($key+1)]['units'][$label1]=$value1;
    $result['tab'.($key+1)]['units'][$label2]=$value2;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: table has hundreds of rows :(

Comment: Can you change the format of the table? It seems strange that the format is row 1 - label, row 2 - label, row 3 - value for row 1, row 4 - value for row2